# Adding details to low poly model for 3d printing

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing

I am trying to add details to a model in order to 3d print it. The model itself is a [WoW character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTMoY.jpg), but the problem is the low poly count and the lack of details for the armor.
Please, keep in mind that I have very little experience using blender and modeling.

Asking in other forums, people suggested retopology, but I only found tutorials of using retopology to reduce details of models, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi,**
if you need more details, you will have to add more vertices. You can reach it by several ways.

**Globally via mesh modifiers**(you can find it in context menu, which is defaultly on right side): Subdivision(Don't forget to use "Simple" option) or Multiresolution.

**For specific parts:** Edit mode -> Select vertices/lines/faces -> Right click -> Subdivide - You can also change some parameters(smoothness, number of cuts, ...)

There's also **dyntopo** - it's tool for sculpting, but it can cause unwanted results for 3d printing.

Don't forget some too detailed parts would be better to separate to more prints.

I hope this is that what you needed to know.